# how multiprocessing.Pipes work in python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I try to understand how does pipes work. I was wrote some example code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import random
import time
import os

def f(conn):
    i = 0
    while 1:
        i+=1
        s = [i, os.getpid()]
        conn.send(s)
        print 'p', s
        time.sleep(.3)
    conn.close()

def b(conn):
    while 1:        
        r =  conn.recv()        
        time.sleep(random.Random().randint(1,5))
        print r, os.getpid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    s = Process(target=f, args=(parent_conn,))
    s.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    s1 = Process(target=b, args=(child_conn,))
    s1.start()
    c = Process(target=b, args=(child_conn,))
    c.start()

    s.join()
    s1.join()
    c.join()
```

And got interesting result:
[image]

Do I understand correctly that `conn.recv()` receives is not next element in the pipe, and one that he intended? Or something like this? What size is the tube buffer? Is it possible to know the count of elements in the pipe?

Comment: It is next element in the pipe but the order of reading by the reader processes is arbitrary and given that you're sleeping a random time in each process after reading, no order can be guaranteed.

Comment: Thanks, i understand my mistake with `time.sleep()`.